# EACCES: permission denied when installing an NPM package globally

Tags: firebase, npm, firebase-tools

I need to install firebase tools for firebase hosting. So I review the documentation and I run the command `sudo npm install -g firebase-tools` but this appears in my terminal.

```
npm WARN deprecated request@2.88.2: request has been deprecated, see https://github.com/request/request/issues/3142
npm WARN deprecated xmldom@0.1.31: Deprecated due to CVE-2021-21366 resolved in 0.5.0
npm WARN deprecated har-validator@5.1.5: this library is no longer supported /usr/local/bin/firebase -> /usr/local/lib/node_modules/firebase-tools/lib/bin/firebase.js  

npm ERR! code EACCES
npm ERR! syscall /usr/local/lib
npm ERR! errno -13
npm ERR! Error: EACCES: permission denied, acces '/usr/local/lib'
npm ERR! {[Error: EACCES: permission denied, acces '/usr/local/lib']
npm ERR! stack:
npm ERR! 'Error: EACCES: permission denied, acces \'/usr/local/lib\'',
npm ERR! errno: -13,
npm ERR! code: 'EACCES',
npm ERR! syscall: 'access',
npm ERR! path: '/usr/local/lib' }
npm ERR!
npm ERR! The operation was rejected by your operating system.
npm ERR! It is likely you do not have the permissions to access this file as the current user
npm ERR! 
npm ERR! If you believe this might be a permissions issue, please double-check the
npm ERR! permissions of the file and its containing directories, or try running
npm ERR! the command as root/Administrator.
```

Answer (score 1):

This issue is related to permissions and can be resolved by installing a node version manager.

> If you see an [EACCES error](https://docs.npmjs.com/resolving-eacces-permissions-errors-when-installing-packages-globally) when you try to install a package globally, you can either:

Reinstall npm with a node version manager (recommended),

or

Manually change npm's default directory

> This is the best way to avoid permissions issues. To reinstall npm with a node version manager, follow the steps in "[Downloading and installing Node.js and npm](https://docs.npmjs.com/downloading-and-installing-node-js-and-npm)". You do not need to remove your current version of npm or Node.js before installing a node version manager.

Comment: A link to a solution is welcome, but please ensure your answer is useful without it: [add context around the link](//meta.stackexchange.com/a/8259) so your fellow users will have some idea what it is and why it’s there, then quote the most relevant part of the page you're linking to in case the target page is unavailable. [Answers that are little more than a link may be deleted.](/help/deleted-answers)

Comment: While this link may answer the question, it is better to include the essential parts of the answer here and provide the link for reference.  Link-only answers can become invalid if the linked page changes. - [From Review](/review/low-quality-posts/28627938)

Comment: Thank you for your feedback @EricSchaefer I am new to this and wanted to add some value to the site. I have since edited my answer in hopes it is more helpful to others.

Comment: Thank you also @Yatin it seems I cannot add 2 users to my comment.